# symbol '_' in MySql request

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, ftp-server, proftpd

When i decide to up proftpd server i have a problem with MySQL.
The problem was a syntax error (1064) which was caused by symbol '_' in MySql request.

Proftpd version:

> ProFTPD Version 1.3.5

MySQL version:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.3' )

Request: 
logs every time when user log in.

> SQLLog PASS counter_login
>
> SQLNamedQuery counter_login UPDATE "`last_login`=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), `login_count`=`login_count`+1 WHERE `username`='%u'" `users`

Error in sql.log:

> 2015-07-02 21:43:09,163 mod_sql/4.3[21872]: error: '1064'
>   2015-07-02 21:43:09,163 mod_sql/4.3[21872]: message: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
>   syntax to use near '; SET `last_login`=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), `login_count`=`login_count` WHERE `username' at line 1'

when i # this and another the same requests, there are no errors.

And in request of Authenticate in /etc/proftpd/sql.conf which show proftpd server, where he needs to take information of users in db,

> SQLAuthenticate users groups

while i put a name of table 'users' its all OK, but when the name of table is 'users_ftp' (of course i rename table in db and in config (/etc/proftpd/sql.conf)) when i restart proftpd server, it doesnt start.

> proftpd[21522]: fatal: SQLAuthenticate: unknown argument on line 34 of '/etc/proftpd/sql.conf'
>   failed!

Comment: What is the symbol \ in login_count+1 \ WHERE

Comment: sorry symbol copied from manyal. in cfg it doesnt contains

Comment: If you configure a `SQLLogFile`, and then try your login, what does that `SQLLogFile` show?